# hide share button from QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, swift

I need to hide the share button button from QLPreviewController

this is the original code to show PDF (for example) into new view

```
var previewItem = NSURL()
func preview(_command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand){
 self.previewItem = fileLocationURL! as NSURL
 let previewController = QLPreviewController();
 previewController.dataSource = self;
 self.viewController?.present(previewController, animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

```
extension PreviewAnyFile: QLPreviewControllerDataSource {
    func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
        return self.previewItem as QLPreviewItem
    }
}
```

[image: developers need to remove share button]

i tried this code (superclass the QLPreviewController into QLSPreviewController ) but the share button still exist

```
class QLSPreviewController : QLPreviewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true )
        //This hides the share item
        if let add =  self.children.first as? UINavigationController {
            if let layoutContainerView  = add.view.subviews[1] as? UINavigationBar {
                 layoutContainerView.subviews[2].subviews[1].isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to modify the source of the QLSPreviewController?

Comment: To create a custom PDF viewer you should subclass `PDFView`

Comment: @flanker yes I have,

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the QLPreviewController and override `viewWillLayoutSubviews`:

```
class PicturePreviewViewController: QLPreviewController {
        
       override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
          super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
                        
          // Hide share button.
          if let navigationController = children.first as? UINavigationController,
          let shareItem = navigationController.toolbar.items?.first as? UIBarButtonItem {
             shareItem.isEnabled = false
             shareItem.tintColor = .clear
          }
       }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on a couple of reasonably safe assumptions:

- that your PDF viewer class is subclassed from a UIViewController
- the navigationBar comes from a navigation controller and isn't manually created

you should just be able to remove the UBarButtonItem

from inside ViewDidLoad:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = []
```

or from outside the class if needs be:

```
myPDFViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = []
```